DB query performance issue when params are used
I am using Hibernate + oracle sql. Here is query
 @Query("SELECT * FROM Schema.Road WHERE status IN (:statuses)")
List<Rescue> findByStatusIn(@Param("statuses") Collection<String> statuses); 

The above query runs faster than below
List<Rescue> findByStatusIn("SELECT * FROM Schema.Road WHERE status IN ('NEW', 'PENDING', 'STATUS1', 'STATUS2', 'INPROGRESS', 'STATUS3'))", nativeQuery = true); 

Essentially, the difference is only with usage of string literals for STATUS.

Why is the second option faster?
For first option with params, why is the DB team able to see that this query is run using params. My understand is that hibernate will do all the conversion to a HARDCODED query and run on my behalf. Is it not the case?
As per DB teams suggestions, If I have to use option 2, it makes my code bad, Is there a better way to achieve this?(Note: I usually have 2 sets of STATUS that I pass)

OR
Can I write below code in some way either native or jpql?
jpqL:
 @Query("SELECT * FROM Schema.Road WHERE status IN (" + MyClass.getRightStatusList() + ")")
List<Rescue> findByStatusIn(); 

native:
List<Rescue> findByStatusIn("SELECT * FROM Schema.Road WHERE status IN (" + String.join(",", MyClass.getRightStatusList()) + "))", nativeQuery = true); 


Your understanding is wrong. Hibernate will send a prepared statement and parameters, the db server will replace the parameters in the prepared statement. So no it will not send a hardcoded query.

Thanks for the info @M.Deinum. Any help around a good fix for the issue?

What are you measuring? I doubt that there is any difference in actual query execution but rather in the mapping. The first is using JPQL and will use more of the mapping information, the second is plain SQL which will use less of the mapping information for query creation. So I highly doubt it is the actual query that is slower but rather the result mapping or the query that is being generated.

I ma measuring the execution time. Oracle has some specific way to look/search for and in this case if string literals are used its quite faster then with params. I got his detail from our DB side so I done know the exact inner details as to why/how there could be difference?

So you aren't measuring the query performance, which is what I was hinting at as it will use different paths. Check the actual query or queries that are executed in both situations I suspect the JPQL case is different then what you are doing here (or maybe even issuing additional queries for more information). As stated I doubt the actual query execution is different but it is the pattern of retrieval that is different. Get the actual queries, check what is actually going on instead of this. There is something else that is causing the delay, find that.

These are simple queries and I see the difference in time for both(with and without variables)

You are measuring the execution time of the method not the execution time of the query. As stated those are different things, if you would only measure the query performance the difference would be hardly noticable. But as I try to convey for a while is that you are measuring a lot more then "just query execution time" and what is being done with both ways of running a query (JPQL vs. SQL) is also different.

@user578219 that is expected the queries w/o bind variables are in general faster, especially in cases when we are dealing with skewed distributions of data, the rationale is following: single execution plan, obviously, can't cover all possible cases.

@AndreyB.Panfilov, Generally speaking, this is very common scenario, what is the recommendation in such a case. Changing this to a nativeQuery? or what? since the bind vars are comparatively slower

please check https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-prevent-execution-plan-troubles-when-querying-skewed-data-with-jooq/ - IMO, that provides good thoughts/insides on "bind vars vs literals" topic, and, yes, that is OK to use literals in some cases. However, your desire to replace jpql with native is not clear for me: you may write the same in jpql (I'm not sure about recent versions of HBN, but 5.6.x do not replace literals with bind vars) - if "the same" jpql demonstrates poor performance that does mean there are some issues with your model, as @M.Deinum has stated previously.

Thanks @AndreyB.Panfilov, I plan to use literals jpql itself  but the main issue is: today I have a 3 sets of Status list that I have a separate method to get.  But now I will have to have 3 jpql methods based on literals, makes my STATUS mgmt code useless.
